# How do I authorise multiple client applications to access my Azure storage resources?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, identity, rbac

I am building a Node JS application that runs on different clients' on-premises hardware.
I want that application to log data to my Azure storage tables.
(In the future, the application may need to use other Azure services.)
How should I authorise the various instances of my application to access my tables?

I'd like to have each different client restricted to different tables, and with only add and read access - no update or delete.

I'd like to be able to revoke a single client's access instantly, if required, without affecting other clients.

I considered 3 options:

- I considered making a separate storage account for each client, and giving the client an access key for that account. But this would give full access (including update and delete).
- I considered creating a Stored Access Policy (SAP) for each client, and then create a Shared Access Signature (SAS) on the policy. The client could connect with the Shared Access Signature [(as described here)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fqueues%2Ftoc.json#controlling-a-sas-with-a-stored-access-policy). The main disadvantage I see with this is that if I want the client's application to have access to several tables, I would need a separate SAP and SAS for each table. I this adds management overhead.
- Since an app is another form of identity, I considered [registering an app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal) to create an identity for each instance of my software. But I wasn't sure how to (a) get the application to pass credentials to azure storage or (b) grant authority to the app to read/add to the table.

In AWS, I have solved this problem by creating IAM Users. The keys are made accessible to the Node JS code through environment variables.

But in Azure, my organisation has an Active Directory, and I am not an administrator for that directory. I don't see how to create Azure Users for the purpose of accessing my tables without being an administrator.

Does anyone have any thoughts or advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned that there is no SAS token for each table. In your case, I recommand that you could give separate storage account for each client with SAS token not full access.

Authenticate access to Azure table is **not supported** currently. Azure AD integration is available for the **Blob** and **Queue** services **only** in the **preview.**

For more information about Authenticating access to Azure blobs and queues using Azure Active Directory (Preview), please refer to the Azure [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad).

Answer (score 0):

I had a little trouble finding information about *exactly* how to use the SAS from Node in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-nodejs), so I thought it might be useful to post my code sample here for reference.

The steps I followed were:

1. Created a new storage account (using Azure portal). I will use a separate storage account per client as suggested by @TomSun.
2. Created a new table inside the account. I downloaded and used Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer to do this and the remaining steps. The Storage Explorer available in the portal doesn't yet work with tables - only blobs, files, and queues.
3. Created an Access Policy on the table. (Right click on the table, choose Manage Access Policies...)
4. Create a Shared Access Signature. (Right click on the table, choose Get Shared Access Signature..., select the policy created above.
5. Copy the resulting URL and the query string for reference in the code below. Note that the URL contains the query string.
6. In a fresh folder on my PC, run `npm init` to set up the node project.
7. `npm install azure-storage` to download the library.
8. Create a file called `index.js` with the contents shown below.
9. `node index.js` to run the code.

Note that in the code below I've modified the names of my account, table, sasToken, etc. Don't expect it to work with just copy-and-paste!

```js
const azure = require('azure-storage');
const sasUri = 'https://myaccount.table.core.windows.net/mytable';
const sasQuery = 'sv=2018-03-28&si=saspolicy&tn=mytable&sig=1%2FgfWdreRKfWpRjhRy3E8MiHDIxH35SPZY5ssU8lKw%3D';
const tableService = new azure.TableService(null,null,sasUri,sasQuery);
const item = {
  PartitionKey: {'_':'keyvalue'},
  RowKey: {'_':'2018-10-10T03:17:21Z'},
  Col1: {'_':23},
  Col2: {'_':423}
};
tableService.insertEntity('mytable',item,function(err,result,response){
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log('success');
    console.log('result = '+JSON.stringify(result,null,'  '));
    console.log('response = '+JSON.stringify(response,null,'  '));
  }
});
```

My next challenge is to find documentation describing the `'_'` keys used in the entity for insertion. It looks like the underscore is used for the value, and a $ can be used for types, although types are guessed if not specified. There's an [entityGenerator function](https://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/TableUtilities.html#.entityGenerator__anchor) to generate these objects if required.

Comment: Don't forget that if there's a % character in the SAS (as in my example), then it will need to be escaped (doubled) when stored in a Windows environment variable. ```sv=2018-03-28&si=saspolicy&tn=mytable&sig=1%%2FgfWd...```

Comment: I retract the comment above. % characters in environment variables are ok, until you use the chocolatey ```refreshenv``` command. https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/1664